# SQL Statement except

Tags: sql

I want to tlike the name of the product, supplier, category, and inventory quantity that have an inventory quantity of 5 or more **except those products supplied by Spaulding.**   and then sort by supplier and then by inventory quantity.

This is my code, the problem is it shows only items from spaulding with 5 or more inventory quantity:

```
SELECT      ProdName, ProdSupplier, ProdCategory, ProdInvQty
FROM        PRODUCT
WHERE       ProdInvQty  >= 5
AND             ProdSupplier = 'Spaulding'

ORDER BY    ProdSupplier, ProdInvQty;
```

Comment: Why did you add the whole schema if it was only necessary the Product table? Next time try to simplify the question. Also try to avoid images and use text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your ambiguous description, I think you want (Edited)

```
SELECT      ProdName, ProdSupplier, ProdCategory, ProdInvQty
FROM        PRODUCT
WHERE       (ProdInvQty  >= 5 
OR          ProdSupplier = 'Spaulding')

ORDER BY    ProdSupplier, ProdInvQty;
```

Comment: There is an unnecesary condition here

Comment: I can't complain now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      ProdName, ProdSupplier, ProdCategory, ProdInvQty

FROM        PRODUCT

WHERE       ProdInvQty  >= 5

AND         ProdSupplier NOT LIKE 'Spaulding'

ORDER BY    ProdSupplier, ProdInvQty;
```